# calling two functions doing the same job, and accepting only the function which was called later

Tags: javascript

I have two functions function1 and function2. Both are doing same task, say setting some value and both take an arbitrary time to complete (function1 can finish first or function2 can randomly).
I want to find a generic solution that if function function1 and function2 are called in order, then only function2's result is considered (i.e the function which was called last).
It can be done using maintaining a global variable and using that to track which function was called later. Is there a generic solution which can be used multiple times on one page.

```
let a = null

function function1(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    a = 5;
  }, Math.random()*100)
}
function function2(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    a = 10;
  }, Math.random()*100)
}

setInterval(() => {
  function1();
  function2();
  console.log(a);
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use promises:

First, define the functions in a way that they return promises.

Define those promises so that they resolve to an object, and that object contains both finishing time and value.

```
function function1() {
  let b = 5;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ value: b, finishTime: Date.now() });
    }, Math.random() * 100);
  });
}
function function2() {
  let a = 10;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ value: a, finishTime: Date.now() });
    }, Math.random() * 100);
  });
}
```

In setInterval, we use **Promise.all**, which takes an array of promises, waits until all of them finish, then returns all the resolved values.

```
setInterval(async () => {   // make function async so we can use await
  let responses = await Promise.all([function1(), function2()]); // promises resolved objects
  console.log("function1 FinishTime: ", responses[0].finishTime); 
  console.log("function2 FinishTime: ", responses[1].finishTime);

  responses.sort((a, b) => b.finishTime - a.finishTime); // now sort the reponses based on the finishing time

  console.log("last Result: ", responses[0].value); // first index of the array has the larger finishing time, meaning it finished last
}, 2000);
```